# how to do validation in Android EditText within a ListView?

Tags: android, listview

i have one List in which their are two textview and one EditView in single row . I bind these textviews and editview at runtime and now i want to do some validation for edittext inside listview ,but my EditView ID is same for all the Rows, so how can i apply validations in that editview plz help me .

Thanks in advance and Sorry for my poor English

My Code is Here

```
try {
        json = new JSONObject(status);
        getArray_Meter_Reading = new JSONArray();
        getArray_Meter_Reading = json.getJSONArray("meterReadings");

        myList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < getArray_Meter_Reading.length(); i++) {

            map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            String meter_Name = getArray_Meter_Reading.getJSONObject(i)
                    .getString("MeterName").toString();

            String previous_Meter_Reading = getArray_Meter_Reading
                    .getJSONObject(i).getString("PrevMeterReading")
                    .toString();

            map.put("meterName", meter_Name);
            map.put("previousMeterReading", previous_Meter_Reading);

            myList.add(map);

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SimpleAdapter myAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, myList,
            R.layout.meter_reading_list, new String[] {
                    "meterName", "previousMeterReading" }, new int[] { R.id.txt_Meter_Name,
                    R.id.txt_Previous});

    lst.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    lst.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                lst.scrollBy(0, 1);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

And my Xml layout which im buinding with this listview

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="6dip"
android:paddingTop="4dip" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_Meter_Name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:width="140dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_Previous"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:width="100dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ed_Current"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext|actionDone"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:width="100dp" >
</EditText>
```

Comment: "but my EditView ID is same for all the Rows" it's not your only problem only few EditViews exist, not for every row(only for visible ones) ... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You have two way for this.
1. Using Custom Adapter
2.As you are doing..but when you are selecting position then you need to get view id like 

lst.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            lst.scrollBy(0, 1);
        }
        return false;
    }
});

You should take operation on View v.This view will give you differnt id as it have.
I will suggest you to use custom adapter if not resolved this way as you are doing.
```

Comment: can u give me an example for custome adapter so i can go through it .

Comment: list.setAdapter(new customadapter());

Comment: You can see the listview using custom adapter with example.. See this link also http://www.rorraja.blogspot.in/

Answer (score 0):

Build a custom Adapter that uses your HashMap and...

> Whenever you want to do processing with the views in a ListView you
>   need to create a custom adapter that will handle your logic
>   implementation and pass that information to the views as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this using custom adapter...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

list.setAdapter(new customadapter());
}

class customadapter extends BaseAdapter{

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arraylist.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int postion, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.readsggs_row,
                    null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
        }else
        {

                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }
            //for (i = 0; i < DatabaseMethods.sggsbmid.size(); i++) {
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        if(postion%2==0)
        {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#A9BCF5"));
        }else
        {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        }
        holder.textview = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.text);

       <///Like this text view you can use any view that you need////>

        return convertView;
    }
    class ViewHolder {
        TextView textview;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have any problem tell me....Its working code for me and i did as you are doing.